# Nextcloud notifications

Tags: notifications, synchronization, webhooks, webdav, nextcloud

I'm working in a project in which I need to record files information in the database whenever a file is added or modified so they remain synchronized. Those files are suposed to be stored in a Nextcloud server so, does Nextcloud have a way to notificate those changes (e.g. a webhook)? If it doesn't, could I achieve something similar using the webdav protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a hook mechanism, see `postCreate (\OCP\Files\Node $node)` on https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/12/developer_manual/app/hooks.html